# Opa: How to store short term data clientside?

Tags: opa

Newbie question here,

I'm trying to store persistent data on the client in my Opa program. It's fine if this is exposed to the user as it's non-critical (it's essentially a nickname).  In PHP or similar, I would use a cookie. I'm not sure how to do this in Opa since I need the data to persist between multiple pages.

I don't want to use a database since this is only a very tiny bit of information and I have no semi-unique way of identifying clients to match up a db record.

Any guidance here?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [UserContext](http://doc.opalang.org/module/stdlib.core.web.context/UserContext).

Description of the module can be found in the source code : https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/blob/v1903/stdlib/core/web/context/user_context.opa#L33